# override javascript in framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

I have a HTML page posts.html in Framework7. Here is the JS code for the posts.html part.

```
myApp.onPageInit('posts', function (page) {
    openPostsPageFromDB(function(html){
        html = '<ul>'+html+'</ul>';
        $$(".posts-page div.posts").html(html);
        pageJS();
    });
});
function pageJS(){
    $$(".post a,.post .post-channel-image,.post #tags").on("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

openPostsPageFromDB returns HTML content after fetching values from DB. I replace the HTML content of posts.html with the corresponding return value and then call pageJS() to override the click event handler on certain elements in HTML.

But, the events are not being overriden and event handlers defined by default in Framework7 are getting fired. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Oh. That's Framework7's selector. [framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/dom.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery method `.on("click",function(e){})` just adds another event listener to the event listeners queue of the element. So, in your case if you want to cancel all click event listeners, you would need something like this:

```
.unbind('click');
```

**Update #1**

The `unbind` method has been depricated as of jQuery 1.7, so you should instead use `off` method.

```
.off('click');
```

Comment: But I am doing e.stopPropagation(); which should stop the propagation of event to children and hence the event should not get fired if I click on them.

Comment: @skjindal93 The `e.stopPropagation()` gets called once all other event listeners  already have been called. So, you can't achieve your goal by stopping propagation. You should instead turn off _all_ click event listeners in order to cancel click event.